# Unable to link pre-built LAPACKE library in CMake C project

Tags: c, cmake, continuous-integration, lapack, lapacke

I would like to use CI for building my `C` project that I manage with `cmake`. The project will heavily employ Fortran's BLAS and LAPACK through CBLAS and LAPACKE. The `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(collision-detection
    C
    Fortran
)

#include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/lapack-3.12.0/build/include)
#link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/lapack-3.12.0/build/lib)
message("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/lapack-3.12.0/build/lib")

add_executable(helloworld_lapacke src/helloworld_lapacke.c)
target_include_directories(helloworld_lapacke PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/lapack-3.12.0/build/include/)
target_link_directories(helloworld_lapacke PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/lapack-3.12.0/build/lib/)
target_link_libraries(helloworld_lapacke PRIVATE
    blas cblas
    lapack lapacke
)
```

Currently I have tried using `add_subdirectory()` only for a pure Fortran executable linked against BLAS and LAPACK and it works but I am not familiar with CBLAS and LAPACKE.

The reason why I am adding `lapacke` (and all of its dependencies) to my project like this is that the package I am using (see [here](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/archive/refs/tags/v3.12.0.tar.gz) for direct download or [here](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/) for documentation on it) is being built in a separate CI job. Another one takes care of the executable and links it against the artifacts from the job that builds `lapacke`.

That is why the binaries (static, `.a` on Linux) and header files are made available via paths relative to the project (here `<PROJECT_ROOT>/deps/lapack-3.12.0/build/` with `lib` and `include` subdirectories).

If I run the `CMakeLists.txt` the building fails with an error from the linker:

```
myproject/deps/lapack-3.12.0/build/lib/liblapacke.a(lapacke_dgels_work.c.o): in function `LAPACKE_dgels_work':
lapacke_dgels_work.c:(.text+0x1c3): undefined reference to `dgels_'
/usr/bin/ld: lapacke_dgels_work.c:(.text+0x2ee): undefined reference to `dgels_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloworld_lapacke.dir/build.make:97: helloworld_lapacke] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/helloworld_lapacke.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

For reproducing the error here is the C code that uses `lapacke`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   double a[5][3] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 5, 4, 3};
   double b[5][2] = {-10, -3, 12, 14, 14, 12, 16, 16, 18, 16};
   lapack_int info, m, n, lda, ldb, nrhs;
   int i, j;

   m = 5;
   n = 3;
   nrhs = 2;
   lda = 3;
   ldb = 2;

   info = LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'N', m, n, nrhs, *a, lda, *b, ldb);

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < nrhs; j++)
      {
         printf("%lf ", b[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   return (info);
}
```

**Note:** I do believe the archive I am using is the same as the contents of [this repository](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack)

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152578/link-error-undefined-reference-to-dgels-in-lapack) (and its answer)? It seems about the same error message which you got.

Comment: Indeed, that helped! However, it needs to be mentioned that for my case I have `lapacke > lapack > cblas > blas > gfortran > m`, with the last one weirdly enough being `libm`, which has to be explicitly added to the linker's list of libraries. If you would like to post the answer, I will approve it right away. You just need to post `target_link_libraries(helloworld_lapacke PRIVATE lapacke lapack cblas blas gfortran m)` :)

Comment: I don't think that every variation of the given error message requires separate question post, so I marked yours one as a duplicate. If you want to publish the linking chain specific for your variants of LAPACK/BLAS, then you could add an answer to the duplicate question.